# VBA Data Validation List

Tags: excel, vba, validation

So I have the Following Problem:

I have the following code:

```
Dim FM As String

Cells(TR, 2).Select
RA = ActiveCell.Address
Cells(20, LC).Select
RA2 = ActiveCell.Address

FM = "=XLookup(" & RA & ",KinderDropDown!$A$1#,KinderDropDown!$A$2:" & RA2 & ",""Kein Kind vorhanden"")

With Range("H2").Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:= FM
End With
```

Just for additional informaion, the original Formula is:

```
 "=XVERWEIS($B$2;KinderDropDown!$A$1#;KinderDropDown!$A$2:$D$3;""Kein Kind vorhanden"")"
```

I have also tested it with the following:

```
With Range("H2").Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:="=Today()"
End With
```

I don't know if it makes a differance but H2 is a cell in a formated table.

Regardless of the way I did it the error is always 1004.

Also the main gool is to add the Validation to specific cells.
So in the completed version it would be something like this:

```
Cells(TR, 8).Select
With Selection.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:=FM
End With
```

As said I tried adjusting the formula's but since even the simple =Today() isn't working I feel the problem is something else.
The debugger always stops at the .Add part of the macro.
I tried alot of different ways writing the formula but it didn't make a differance.

I do have a less interesting workaround but that doesn't help me with my curiosity and also doesnt help me develop my skills. So if anybody knows what the problem is I would be really greatfull.

Oh I did look through allot of forum posts and such but nothing really helped. However Maybe I misread something.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it somewhat fixed:

```
^FM = "=XLOOKUP(" & RA & ",KinderDropDown!$A$1#,KinderDropDown!$A$2:" & RA2 & ",""Kein Kind vorhanden"")"

Cells(TR, 8).Select
With Selection.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:=FM
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
End With
```

just doesn't loop